# extra white space to the right in my mobile website

Tags: iphone, mobile, web, space, extra

My mobile site, http://hoagfrm.orangegrids.com/index.php?id=51, is developed with 320px size. Still i can see an extra white space to the right in an iPhone. Can someone hep to figure this out please

Comment: I checked your site from Safari browser. It still has a white space when you scroll the site from right to left. May be it's a problem with your site. Did you check your WebView width?.

Comment: hi: this is an HTML page and is developed using standard HTML/CSS. Appreciate if you can let me know which area i need to look if this is a problem with my site

Comment: Hi:I finally solved this by using the META vieport plugin and restricting the page width using CSS to 320px.